# Should I use mount() or /usr/bin/mount

Tags: c++, linux, mount

I want to mount a filesystem using C++. Should I use the `mount()` system call, or just execute the `mount` binary?

Obviously a system call is going to be faster, and I'm going to waste less time building command-line arguments and parsing error messages and stuff. However, having read mount(2), it is unclear to me what restrictions (if any) there are on the arguments.

I particularly want to be able to mount disk image files as well as actual physical disks. And I also want to be able to mount individual filesystems by specifying an offset from the start of the device / image. I don't know whether you can do that with a single call to `mount()`, or whether you would need to manually create loop devices first. (I also don't know how hard it is to create a loop device — I *presume* it's fairly easy...)

If setting this stuff up right is fairly complicated, then it's probably simpler and easier to call the `mount` binary. But if it's just one system call, calling `mount()` directly seems cleaner. So which one is likely to give me the fewest problems?

Comment: Given the frequency with which you usually mount a filesystem, I wouldn't give a crap about performance. I would just try the system call as it's definitely *cleaner*, and if I can't get it to work within 15 minutes - binary here I come. Do keep in mind that you shouldn't trust it to be at `/usr/bin/mount` - always call `which mount` to determine whether it is supported, and where it is.

Comment: Generally using system commands is to be avoided; I assume you are aware of that...

Comment: You can grab the source code of `mount` and copy&paste what you need. Not considering license issues...

Comment: BTW, why your program wants to mount a filesystem? Why can't it require the filesystem to be already mounted? Who is in charge of unmounting the filesystem?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm also in charge of unmounting it afterwards. Presumably that's a far simpler task.

Comment: Note that in case of a desktop application for Linux it might be preferable to use a subsystem more geared towards normal users, like UDisks.

Comment: Didn't it take longer to ask this question than to actually code it? mount() is quite simple and well described in the [`man` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html). Same with [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Nayden suggested running `strace mount`, which isn't a bad idea.

Having done this, it appears that `mount` is doing a *hell* of a lot of work. It looks like it does create a loop device and mount that. (Which means it needs to figure out what the next unused loop device number is, etc.) It sounds like you may also need to manually figure out the filesystem type.

In short, it looks to me like one simple call to the `mount` binary is probably going to be far less work than trying to recreate everything that program does. I had thought the intelligence is in the kernel, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is use the system call.
If you want to know the exact call you need to make, run mount via the shell under strace or gdb.

Comment: This won't easily work for doing what `mount -t auto` command does. The [mount(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) syscall needs to know the file system type.

Answer (score 0):

**System call mount():**
pros:
- non blocking(i.e. your process is still responsive).
- kind of faster, as you don't spend time on creation of new process, thread.
cons:
- you need to specify the filesystem type, mount flags, data(some special stuff used by some filesystems, maybe NULL).
- you can mount image file, but there is a necessity to take care about having free loop device and associating it with your image.
- looks if your code need to cover all possible use cases, you may end with self-written mount tool :)

**Mount tool:**
pros:
- easier to use, as less arguments need to specify by default.
- no need to create loop device, associate it with image, etc(in case of image mount).
cons:
- when it goes about calling mount tool from c++ code via system, fork-exec etc, your process will be blocked, if wait() would be used. Some applications are sensible to such block(i.e. somebody may depend on your application and wait for answer, while mount would be in progress)

If you are interested in how to mount image via mount system call, here is a simple proof of concept, based on:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html
https://linux.die.net/man/2/mount
Be aware not to use such code in production, as there is no single check on return values, exceptions etc :). Anyway it compiles, and works on my machine. Should be ran with root.

```
#include <sys/mount.h>  //mount
#include <sys/ioctl.h>  //ioctl
#include <sys/stat.h>   //open
#include <linux/loop.h> //LOOP_SET_FD
#include <fcntl.h>      //open
#include <cstdio>       // declaration of ::fileno
#include <cstdint>      //int32_t
#include <sstream>      //std::stringstream
#include <string>

constexpr char IMAGE_NAME[] = "image.img";       //of course we need this file to be present in same folder as built tool
constexpr char MOUNT_POINT[] = "/tmp/image_mnt"; //of course we need this folder already created
constexpr char FILESYSTEM_TYPE[] = "ext4";
constexpr char DEV_LOOP_CONTROL[] = "/dev/loop-control";
constexpr char DEV_LOOP_PREFIX[] = "/dev/loop";
constexpr int32_t MOUNT_FLAGS = MS_RDONLY;

int main()
{
    const auto loop_control = std::fopen(DEV_LOOP_CONTROL, "r");
    const auto loop_control_fd = fileno(loop_control);
    const auto devnr = ioctl(loop_control_fd, LOOP_CTL_GET_FREE);
    std::stringstream loopname;
    loopname << DEV_LOOP_PREFIX << devnr;
    const auto loop_device_name = loopname.str();
    const auto loop_device = std::fopen(loop_device_name.c_str(), "r");
    const auto loop_device_fd = fileno(loop_device);
    const auto image = std::fopen(IMAGE_NAME, "r");
    const auto image_fd = fileno(image);
    //Associate the loop device with the open file whose file descriptor is passed as the (third) ioctl(2) argument.
    ioctl(loop_device_fd, LOOP_SET_FD, image_fd);
    const auto result = mount(loop_device_name.c_str(), MOUNT_POINT, FILESYSTEM_TYPE, MOUNT_FLAGS, NULL);
    ioctl(loop_device_fd, LOOP_CLR_FD, 0);
    return result;
}
```